# How would I parameterise this endpoint using Retrofit please?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Say I want to query an an API which has a server method for searching for a field containing certain text like so:

```
http://server:2001/tms/xdata/Customer?$filter=contains(Name, 'Walker')
```

In Android Studio using Kotlin I would make an interface something like this:

```
    @GET("/tms/xdata/Customer")
    suspend fun fetchAllProductsContaining(@Query("name") searchTerm: String): CustomersResponse
```

which if I pass a single character 'e' as the searchTerm would give me:

```
http://server:2001/tms/xdata/Customer?name=e
```

However I need it to look like this:

```
http://server:2001/tms/xdata/Customer?%24filter=contains(lower(name)%2C'e')
```

As I want it to be case insensitive, also notice the text to search for has to have single quotes around it.

I would very much appreciate any help you guys might have.  The server is written in Delphi using [TMS XData](http://www.tmssoftware.biz/business/xdata/doc/web/index.html)

Comment: I don't understand what this question has to do with the Delphi language. Because the server is  written in Delphi doesn't mean that the post is about that topic. Where is the relationship to any Delphi code involved that would merit the use of that tag?

Comment: That still does not explain your use of the Delphi tag, as your question has absolutely nothing to do with Delphi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use QueryMap.
Call the function this way:

```
    suspend fun searchProductsRetrofit(searchTerm: String): List<Product> {
        val options: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
        options["\$filter"] = "contains(lower(Name),'$searchTerm')"
        return retrofit().getProducts(options).value
    }
```

In your API interface configure it to use the passed in data as follows:

```
    @GET("/pmi/civic_amenity/CaProduct")
    suspend fun getProducts(@QueryMap options: Map<String, String>): ProductsResponse
```